# Not able to set JVM heap size on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Java SE Platform

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jvm, heap-size

I have a Spring Boot app deployend on Elastic Beanstalk using a single EC2 t2.micro instance (1GB RAM).

I need to increase my app's JVM Heap size but I'm not being able to do so. The things I have tried are:

- Setting a `JAVA_OPTS` variable in the enviroment configuration in the EB console with the value `-Xms512m -Xmx896m`.
- Deploying the app with a `Procfile` in the project root folder what contains the following line: `web: java -jar <relative-path-to-jar> -Xms512m -Xmx896m`

What else could I try?

*Note: To check the JVM heap size of the running app I ssh into the instance and use the `jstat` command as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44095604/5938293) describes. Calculating the max value always gives me 256MB which is the dafault.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

My Spring Boot project was a multi-module one:

- base_module (POM type)

  - .elasticbeanstalk

    - config.yaml
  - module1 (delpyed module. imports module2 and module3 in the pom.xml)
  - module2
  - module3
  - Procfile

One of the modules (the one's jar I was deploying) imported the other ones. My mistake was that I was putting the `Procfile` in the root of the base module. Also in the `config.yaml` file I was putting the following lines:

```
deploy:
    artifact: module1/target/app.jar
```

So the command `eb deploy` wasn't taking in account the `Procfile`.

The solution was to move the `.elasticbeanstalk` folder into the `module1` folder, removing the lines I said above from the `config.yaml` and to add a `Procfile` in the root of `module1` with the following line:

```
web: java -jar target/app.jar -Xmx896M
```

The final project structure was:

- base_module (POM type)

  - module1 (delpyed module. imports module2 and module3 in the pom.xml)

    - .elasticbeanstalk

      - config.yaml
    - src
    - target
  - Procfile
  - module2
  - module3

Hope it helps somebody!

Comment: when running this configuration you indeed get something like : 
ps aux | grep java returning java - jar jarname.jar -Xms2g -Xmx4g . However, when running sudo jmap -heap [process pid] you get a 2GB maximum heapsize (in my case on an 8GB Elastic Beanstalk server). What could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Create a zip file which contains your application.jar and the Proc file.Upload and deploy this in the elasticbeanstalk.

Write the below line in your Procfile
web: java -jar application.jar -Xmx896M