# AWS Elastic Beanstalk - Setting JVM Options (Heapspace)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Good day.

I am running a Java Application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have to increase the heapspace, normally I would do so via -Xmx and Xms.

How do I accomplish this on AWS?

I'm deploying it in the most simple way possible - uploading a jarfile and running it. I've already found this solution on here:

[Not able to set JVM heap size on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Java SE Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990349/not-able-to-set-jvm-heap-size-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-java-se-platform)

Putting a Procfile into a .zip together with my .jar is accepted when deploying but changes nothing. I really am out of ideas, can anyone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to set JVM heap size on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Java SE Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990349/not-able-to-set-jvm-heap-size-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-java-se-platform)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. I've already referenced this thread in my question because I tried setting JAVA_OPTS and putting a procfile to my .jar. This lead to no errors but changed nothing nonetheless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After trying several different things (.Config file or Procfile in .zip, changing the Serverside JVM's default heap size and Adding JAVA_OPTS to beanstalk configuration) it finally worked out.

Instead of "JAVA_OPTS", simply add
"_JAVA_OPTIONS"
with the value
"-Xmx[size]m" ([size] representing the desired heap size in bytes)
to your Beanstalk Environment's Configurations; it's found under
"Configuration"->"Software"->"Environment Properties".

I hope this will save someone the time it took me to find out.

Comment: I want to pass -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=60 to elasticbeanstalk JAVA 8 SE, is that achieved in the same way?

Comment: I never had to do this. I guess you just have to try, sorry.

Comment: For JDK 9+, "JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS" is the recommended variable to use instead of "_JAVA_OPTIONS"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52986487/what-is-the-difference-between-jdk-java-options-and-java-tool-options-when-using

Comment: I can confirm that _JAVA_OPTIONS with value get picked correctly by the JVM in beanstalk configuration

Example: _JAVA_OPTIONS with value -verbose:gc